# ¿Por qué me devuelve "Lo siento" al escapar texto?

Tags: javascript, html

Esta web escapa texto. [Aquí está el link](https://norfipc.com/inf/javascript-como-escapar-ocultar-codigo-paginas-web.html#convert). Extrayendo la función que se encarga de escapar el texto (la he sacado del código fuente. [Aquí](http://view-source:https://norfipc.com/inf/javascript-como-escapar-ocultar-codigo-paginas-web.html#convert)), que es la que hay más adelante, si uso ese código (el extraído), me devuelve "Lo siento", pero en la página eso no ocurre, porque te ofrece el código escapado directamente sin preámbulos. ¿Por qué está ocurriendo eso y hay alguna solución?

```html
<script>
function escapeTxt(os){
 var ns='';
 var t;
 var chr='';
 var cc='';
 var tn='';
 var x867=['\u0061\u0062','\u006E\u006F\u0072\u0066\u0069\u0070\u0063\u002E\u0063\u006F\u006D','\u006F\u0074\u0072\u006F','\u0064\u006F\u006D\u0061\u0069\u006E','\u004C\u006F\u0020\u0073\u0069\u0065\u006E\u0074\u006F'];
 var x869=document[x867[3]];
 for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  tn = i.toString(16);
  if(tn.length<2)tn="0"+tn;
   cc+=tn;
   chr+=unescape('%'+tn);
  }
  cc = cc.toUpperCase();
  os.replace(String.fromCharCode(13)+'',"%13");
  for(q = 0; q < os.length; q++) {
   t = os.substr(q,1);
   for(i=0;i<chr.length;i++){
    if(t==chr.substr(i,1)){
     t=t.replace(chr.substr(i,1),"%"+cc.substr(i*2,2));
     i=chr.length;
    }
   }
   ns+=t;
  }
  if(x867[1]==x869){
   return ns;
  }else {
   return x867[4];
  }
 }

function unescapeTxt(s){
 return unescape(s);
}

function writeOut(){
 document.forms["fa"].output.value="<script type=\'text\/javascript\'>document.write(unescape('"+escapeTxt(document.forms['fa'].f2.value)+"'))<\/script>";
}   


</script>

    <form name="fa" action="">
    <b>Código a escapar</b><br>
    <textarea id="f2" cols="40" rows="10" class="cuadro1">
    &lt;!-- Solo un ejemplo --&gt;
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    alert('Hola');
    &lt;/script&gt;
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <input class="boton" type="button" value="Codificar" onclick="writeOut()" />
    <br /><br>

    <b>Resultado del código escapado</b><br>
    <textarea name="output" onclick="this.select()" rows="10" cols="40" class="cuadro1">
    El código escapado completo aparecerá aquí...
    </textarea><br>
    <input class="boton" type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
    </form><br />
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tu pregunta es muy poco especifica, no queda claro cuál es tu duda, tampoco tu código. Saludos.

Comment: Saludos. Dale formato la parte donde esta el código JavaScript. así puede se entienda lo que implica; así mismo pon una explicación de que es lo que tienes colocado y así se podrá identificar lo que ocurre.

Comment: Ya está editado

Comment: Creo que lo que has copiado como *fuente* está ofuscado, y el propósito es precisamente evitar que copien tan fácilmente una implementación o lógica. Si bien pueden existir herramientas para *des* ofuscar un código, me parece que lo que deberías intentar es hacer tu propia implementación de ofuscado. Saludos

Comment: Entonces, ¿qué programas existen para realizar la acción que has dicho?

Comment: Curiosamente, el código tiene unas pocas líneas para evitar que sea usado fuera de la página del autor, lo que me lleva a preguntarte: ¿Cuál es la idea de ocultar tus códigos? No tiene mucho sentido si estás aprendiendo y recibiendo ayuda en una comunidad como esta.

Comment: @Triby No solo pregunto sobre como escapar texto. La idea de ocultar mis códigos es saber que herramienta estoy usando, aprender a usarla, ocultar mis códigos de posibles plagios, y resolver y aprender de mis dudas.

Comment: Sin embargo, estás pidiendo ayuda para plagiar código de otra página y usarlo para que no plagien el tuyo. Como que algo aquí no es compatible. ¿No crees?

Comment: La respuesta es simple: Devuelve "lo siento" porque tiene protección para evitar plagio. ¿Algo más?

Comment: ¿Sí, y como es eso posible?

Comment: ¿Es oculto? Porque Javascript no lo hace, o al menos que yo sepa

Comment: @Triby No aparece en el código las palabras Lo siento. Es eso precisamente lo que yo quiero aplicar en mis códigos

Comment: ¿Me lo puedes decir, por favor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sinceramente, no entiendo porqué perder el tiempo tratando de "ocultar" código cuando es perfectamente visible al usar el inspector del navegador.

En cuanto a porqué aparece "Lo siento":

```js
var x867=['\u0061\u0062','\u006E\u006F\u0072\u0066\u0069\u0070\u0063\u002E\u0063\u006F\u006D','\u006F\u0074\u0072\u006F','\u0064\u006F\u006D\u0061\u0069\u006E','\u004C\u006F\u0020\u0073\u0069\u0065\u006E\u0074\u006F'];

x867.forEach(texto => console.log(texto));
```

**Nota:** Se me olvidó colocar la función `unescape()` y, sin embargo, el texto *codificado* se puede leer perfectamente en la consola. ¡Qué sabio es el navegador!

Como puedes ver, "Lo siento" es el último elemento de la variable `x867` y aparece porque se hace una validación, buscando un atributo o elemento en `document[domain]`, si lo encuentra y es igual al dominio donde se debe ejecutar el script, devuelve el texto codificado, de lo contrario, devuelve esas dos palabras.

### Conclusión:

Si alguien quiere tu código:

- Novato: No va a poder obtenerlo a menos que esté visible y, si no lo entiende, no podrá usarlo. ¿Te suena familiar?
- Intermedio: Con un poco de conocimientos del lenguaje y del navegador, lo podrá obtener sin problemas.
- Experto: No perderá el tiempo, porque tiene la capacidad suficiente para crear sus propios códigos.

Debo insistir: Me parece poco coherente que tu aprendizaje esté basado en la ayuda que otros te proporcionan y, aún así, quieras ocultar tus códigos, "no sea que alguien te los quiera plagiar".

Comment: El hecho de no estar de acuerdo no implica que la gente no sea amable, simplemente se necesita entender todo el contexto para saber qué y porqué se quiere realizar determinada actividad. Y, de hecho, la amabilidad depende al 99.9% de la actitud al preguntar, responder o comentar. Mis respetos para @gbianchi por mantener su amabilidad y cortesía.

Comment: @Triby No me refiero a estar de acuerdo, sino que en alguna ocasión alguna respuesta, no de gbianchi, sino en la mía o en otras que no lo son, algunas respuestas no suenan muy amables precisamente, o suenan despectivos. Es el claro ejemplo, de la respuesta de "no agregues gracias", que suena un poco desagradable cuando yo lo he agradecido con toda mi buena atención. Prefiero no entrar en más debates